# How does Maven know where to find Java 1.5

Tags: java, maven-2

In `pom.xml` you can:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How does Maven know where I have 1.5 version?

Comment: OT: Is it just me or "pom" really looks very similar to "porn" :) ?

Comment: @Anton: it's probably your font, with my font they are quite differnt ;-)

Comment: I believe it looks in either the JAVA_HOME env variable or it looks in PATH to find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, this will *not* make Maven compile against the Java 1.5 libraries. This will only tell the compiler to accept 1.5-level source code and produce 1.5-level class files.

Your code could still possibly refer to Java 6 classes, as long as your Maven task is run with a Java 6 JVM.

IF you execute:

```
mvn -v
```

The output will show you what version of Java is being used. For example:

```
Apache Maven 2.1.0 (r755702; 2009-03-18 19:10:27+0000)
Java version: 1.6.0_13
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\jre
Default locale: en_IE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows vista" version: "6.0" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it that we are talking about Maven here. I would guess via the JAVA_HOME environmental variable. If Windows do a echo %JAVA_HOME% or Linux do a echo $JAVA_HOME and see.

Oops: Sorry I see it is Maven.

Answer (score 0):

I knew that maven had figured out where to find my JDK without me setting $JAVA_HOME. After removing the default JDK version, Maven was still looking in the original location and throwing an error.

I didn't want to set $JAVA_HOME if there was a mechanism already in place. Eventually I found ~/.mavenrc, which contained the setting of JAVA_HOME.

I fixed this, and presto, things were happy.